# Caddy not forwarding proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, reverse-proxy, caddy

I have a site set up with caddy that serves a react app.  But the proxy part of it doesn't seem to be forwarding requests to the other docker container.  It still shows me the react page on `example.com/api`.

My caddyfile:

```
example.com {
    gzip

    root /app/build    # directory of public pages # Single-page react app

    proxy /staticfiles django:8000 {
        transparent
    }
    proxy /api django:8000 {
        transparent
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of orchestration tools do you use ? docker-compose? can you give the dcker-compose?   Is `/staticfiles` proxy ok ?

Comment: try here https://caddy.community/

Answer (score -1):

### If you're using docker run:

Use --network to connect containers:

```
docker run --rm --network app django    
docker run --rm --network app mycaddydockerimage
```

### If you're using docker-compose:

Use --links:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  django:
    image: django
  mycaddydockerimage:
    image: something
    links:
    - django
```

Comment: Links have been deprecated for some time now. Please use a shared user created network which exists by default with compose file version 2 and greater.